# Ionic SVG stylesheet reference

Tags: css, svg, ionic3

When referencing an SVG element in an object tag you can manipulate it via CSS by placing a stylesheet link in the SVG file. I can't seem to get it to work. I'm placing:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="build/main.css"?>
```

before the SVG tag. And I have a class on the element that I'm referencing in an SCSS file associated with the page the SVG object is part of. I'm thinking that `build/main.css` might not be where that SCSS is transpiled to, but I can't find any good information online.

So how do I select an element of an SVG (preferably not inline) in CSS within an Ionic 3 project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in my case i did this

html folder ->

- digital.svg
- css(folder) -> main.css

> digital.svg

```
<svg id="Digital_svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 96 96">
        <defs>
            <style>
                @import url(css/main.css);
            </style>
        </defs>
        <title>
            Digital
        </title>
        <path class="cls-1 last" d="M73,43.16A4.84,4.84,0,1,1,68.16,48,4.84,4.84,0,0,1,73,43.16m0-1A5.84,5.84,0,1,0,78.84,48,5.85,5.85,0,0,0,73,42.16Z"/>
        <path class="cls-1 first" d="M23,43.16A4.84,4.84,0,1,1,18.16,48,4.84,4.84,0,0,1,23,43.16m0-1A5.84,5.84,0,1,0,28.84,48,5.85,5.85,0,0,0,23,42.16Z"/>
        <circle class="cls-2 third" cx="61.67" cy="48" r="9.44"/>
        <path class="cls-1 secound" d="M45.67,34.72A13.28,13.28,0,1,1,32.39,48,13.3,13.3,0,0,1,45.67,34.72m0-2A15.28,15.28,0,1,0,61,48,15.28,15.28,0,0,0,45.67,32.72Z"/>
    </svg>
```

> css/main.css

```
.cls-1{
    fill:#333;
    }
.cls-2{fill:#2f86c9;}

svg {
    vertical-align: bottom; 
    width: 100%; 
    max-width: 100px !important;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

result

[image]

Comment: This was helpful. By pointing to @import url(../../build/main.css); I can reference the main css. However within the page scss file I had to have the selector outside the page-flow element for it to work. Also worth noting; creating a new css file in assets/css and referencing that in the manner suggested works.